# Как вернуть анимацию SVG в исходное состояние?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, анимация, svg-animation

У меня есть SVG-анимация, подобная этой:

```js
function startAnimation() {
  document.querySelector('#anim-width').beginElement();
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect id="box" x="10" y="10" fill="red" width="10" height="10">
    <animate
      id="anim-width"
      attributeName="width"
      from="10"
      to="80"
      dur="1s"
      fill="freeze"
      begin="click"
    />
    
    <animate
      attributeName="height"
      from="10"
      to="80"
      begin="anim-width.end + 0s"
      dur="1s"
      fill="freeze"
    />
  </rect>
</svg>

<br/>

<button onclick="startAnimation()">Start</button>
```

Я хочу добиться, чтобы красный прямоугольник начинался с размера 10 на 10, и при нажатии кнопки его ширина увеличивается с 10 до 80, а затем height увеличивается до 80 после завершения анимации ширины.

Это отлично работает при первом воспроизведении, но при повторном нажатии кнопки высота начинается с 80 вместо 10.  Как мне сбросить все до исходного состояния и воспроизвести всю анимацию?

Я пробовал добавить `document.querySelector('# box').SetAttribute('height', '10'); в функции` startAnimation()`, но, похоже, это не работает.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to reset an svg animation to its initial state?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68067502/7394871) от участника  [@Hao Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10289265/hao-wu).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68067502/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Я добавляю элемент `<set>` внутри прямоугольника и запускаю элемент `set` внутри функции `startAnimation()`

Элемент `<set>` позволяет установить значение атрибута (в данном случае высоту), как анимация с длительностью `0`.

```js
function startAnimation() {
  document.querySelector("#set").beginElement();
  document.querySelector("#anim-width").beginElement();
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect id="box" x="10" y="10" fill="red" width="10" height="10">
    <animate id="anim-width" attributeName="width" from="10" to="80" dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="click" />

    <animate id="anim-height" attributeName="height" from="10" to="80" begin="anim-width.end + 0s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />

    <set id="set" attributeName="height" to="10"></set>
  </rect>
</svg>

<br />

<button onclick="startAnimation()">Start</button>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68068295/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>

Comment: Интересные выражения, но похоже на суррогат скриптового языка)) : `set`, `anim-width.end + 0s` - те же инструкции, только заключенные в теги и атрибуты элементов. Здорово, есть что поучить.

Comment: Я обратил внимание на `begin: "click"`, попробовал кликнуть на сам объект и все сломал))

Comment: @Leonid Тут очень долго объяснять. Что, как и почему, так сделано. Если кратко, то fill="freeze"  замораживает последний кадр анимации. Анимации уже нет, а картинка осталась на экране. Чтобы  обновить последний кадр, нужно запустить, какую-то другую команду анимации. Вот set - команда анимации, которая возвращает в исходную позицию объект мгновенно.   anim-width.end - это мощное оружие анимации SVG, которого нет у CSS/  это так называемые логические цепочки управления. Можно записать anim-width.end+1s,что означает запуск второй анимации после окончания первой анимации плюс пауза 1 секунда

Comment: Я понял, инструкции читаются хорошо, кроме fill=freeze. То есть до смены кадра не обновляется изображение? Или только не удаляется последний кадр, замораживая изображение в финальной стадии?

Comment: @Leonid Да именно так, замораживается последний кадр. приложение написано немного неграмотно авторами EnSo, нужна защита от повторного клика, чтобы анимация не ломалась (не запускалась вновь) restart="whenNotActive" либо restart="never" Я предлагал тебе придумать, какой-нибудь вопрос по анимации Так же с квадратиком, с каким-нибудь алгоритмомом, последовательностью, так быстее пойдет твоё вхождение в SVG анимации. Поверь, это проще, интересней и мощнее, чем CSS

Comment: Да я пока с синтаксисом не разобрался и с семантикой вообще. А что скоро какое-то революционное обновление SVG обещают? Или это как с Нивой - все ограничится АБС в люксовой версии))) О, да они там собрались включать видео в теги SVG...

Comment: @Leonid Да, значительные обновления будут в SVG2, только вот с 2011 года обещают и когда это будет реально сделано неизвестно. Тат ты синтаксис и будешь учить на моих ответах. Напиши в вопросе простой алгоритм, допустим движение горизонтально вправо на 100px, пауза 1сек, движение вниз 100px, пауза 2сек, влево 100px/  Ну или, что-нибудь посложнее с двумя объектами движения и их взаимосвязью

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126740/discussion-between-leonid-and-alexandr-tt).

Answer (score 3):

Другой вариант - просто использовать элемент `<animate>`, который запускает анимацию, сбрасывая высоту.

```js
document.querySelector("#anim-height").addEventListener("endEvent", enableButton);

function startAnimation() {
  document.querySelector("#start-btn").disabled = true;
  document.querySelector("#anim-start").beginElement();
}


function enableButton()
{
  document.querySelector("#start-btn").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <rect id="box" x="10" y="10" fill="red" width="10" height="10">
    <animate id="anim-start" attributeName="height" to="10" dur="0.01s" fill="freeze" begin="indefinite" />
    <animate id="anim-width" attributeName="width" from="10" to="80" dur="1s" fill="freeze" begin="anim-start.end + 0s" />
    <animate id="anim-height" attributeName="height" from="10" to="80" begin="anim-width.end + 0s" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
  </rect>
</svg>

<br />

<button id="start-btn" onclick="startAnimation()">Start</button>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68069015/7394871) от участника  [@Paul LeBeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1292848/paul-lebeau).</sub>

Comment: Здесь `begin="indefinite"` и все работает как надо.

Comment: @Leonid тут другая механика, которой управляет JS :) Это классика, когда begin="indefinite" в SVG то есть постоянный, непрерывный запуск анимации, этим самым достигается защита от повторных кликов, а когда нужно, то управление перехватsвает JS